proc_macro_derive with a "tag" attribute
I'm trying to implement a derive trait that would look like this:
#[derive(Cacheable)]
#[cacheable(directory = "path/in/cache")]
pub struct Something {
    #[cacheable(id)]
    pub id: String
}

Where the id is just a field that is used to uniquely store the data. Only one of the fields should be marked with id and it doesn't have any data associated with it. We just need the name of the field. e.g. the trait has a fn id() -> String { return self.#id_field.to_string() }
I have it so that I can extract the directory using the deluxe library but I can't figure out how to get the id tag.
fn cacheable_derive_impl(
    item: proc_macro2::TokenStream,
) -> deluxe::Result<proc_macro2::TokenStream> {
    // parse
    let mut ast: syn::DeriveInput = syn::parse2(item)?;

    // extract struct attributes
    let CacheableAttributes { directory } = deluxe::extract_attributes(&mut ast)?;

    // extract field attributes
    // Need to get the single field marked with the id attribute
    let id = if let syn::Data::Struct(s) = &mut ast.data //??
...
}

All of the examples I have found seem to be trying to extract a value for the attribute, or else have the attribute on all the fields.
So the question is, how can I get the field name and use it in the definition?

You can s.fields.iter_mut().find() the one with your desired attribute in attrs⁉

@cafce25 What would that find look like? I have the Attribute but then I don't know how to compare it to "id", i.e. |field| field.attrs.iter().any(|attr| attr.<something?> == "id"). I'm guessing it might be the meta field but the docs are unclear if that would give "id" or "cacheable".

If you're not sure, just run your code and it will tell you. You can use dbg!(attr) to show what the attribute you get looks like for example.

^ like this

@cafce25 thanks! So I can see that there is a token stream in the attributes that has the "id" ident, but the final step of actually extracting that is eluding me. If I changed the marker to simply #[id] then I could use path() to get the "id". In a Meta::List it's "hidden" in the token stream so I guess I need to parse it in some way first? I can't just match on the list and access the token.

I found an answer using parse_nested_meta:
    // extract field attributes
    // Need to get the single field marked with the id attribute
    let id_field = if let syn::Data::Struct(s) = &ast.data {
        s.fields
            .iter()
            .find(|field| {
                field.attrs.iter().any(|attr| {
                    let mut is_id = false;
                    if attr.path().is_ident("cacheable") {
                        attr.parse_nested_meta(|meta| {
                            if meta.path.is_ident("id") {
                                is_id = true;
                            }
                            Ok(())
                        })
                        .unwrap();
                    }
                    is_id
                })
            })
            .map(|field| field.ident.as_ref().unwrap().to_owned())
    } else {
        None
    }
    .ok_or_else(|| syn::Error::new_spanned(&ast, "No field with 'id' attribute found"))?;

I'm not totally happy with how complicated that looks but it works at least.
